# Generic average over multiple entries in a sql column

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a SQL table that looks something like this:

```
| variable | rank |
|__________|______|
|   var1   | 0.3  |
|   var2   | 0.1  |
|   ...    | ...  |
```

I have hundreds of entries in the table with multiple instances of every variable with some associated rank. Is there a way I can tell SQL to take the entries for every variable in the first column and output me an average ranking? What I don't want to do is this:

```
SELECT AVG(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE variable=variable_name;
```

where I would need to specify every single variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is called `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT variable,AVG(column_name)
FROM table_name
--WHERE variable IN (...) -- you still can filter rows based on variable values
GROUP BY variable
```